# How can I display 2 or more .pgm images using CImg library in C++?

Tags: cimg, display, pgm

Im trying to load and display 2 .pgm files in c++
So far I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CImg.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    CImg<unsigned char> image1("pic1.pgm");
    image1.display();
    CImg<unsigned char> image2("pic2.pgm"); 
    image2.display();
}
```

The second image only displays after Ive closed the first one off. Is there a way I can open them both at the same time?
And for future reference, is there a way I can do this with 3 or more images.

Thank you

(sorry for being a noob)

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8754211/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's an even easier way - by making a `CImgList` of your images. Note that I changed `pgm` to `ppm` just to get colour:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    CImg<unsigned char> image1("pic1.ppm");  // red square
    CImg<unsigned char> image2("pic2.ppm");  // blue square
    (image1,image2).display();
}
```

[image]